# Prove that ∀n∈N, (n>3∧ n is prime)→∃q∈N,(n=6q+1∨n=6q+5)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Contradiction or contra-positive? Or is direct easier?

∀n∈N, (n>3∧ n is prime)→∃q∈N,(n=6q+1∨n=6q+5)

Comment: Using MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ will make your postings easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since primes greater than 3 are odd, the only other possible form is 6k + 3. But this is divisible by 3 so is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

In plain text the expression means : Every prime $n$ greater than $3$ has the form $6q+1$ or $6q+5$, which is clearly the case because the numbers $6q,6q+2,6q+3,6q+4$ are divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $ n\mod 6$. Thus any $n > 3$ can be written as $n = 6q + k$ with $0 \le k < 6$. For if $k = 0,2,3,4$, $n$ is divisible by $2$ or $3$ or $6$ so not a prime. Thus for $n$ to be prime, $k = 1$ or $5$.

Comment: Consider $nmod6$ or just $mod 6$ ?